# Android. Secondary preferred app

Tags: android, sms, broadcastreceiver, default, man-in-the-middle

I'm trying to implement something like man-in-the-middle app that will launch specific actions on some broadcasts, activity starts and then launch the secondary default app to do the rest of things.

For example:

1. Facebook (click on web link) -> MyApp (add notification "starting web page") -> Chrome/Firefox
2. Incoming sms -> MyApp (set sound reminder every 2mins) -> Hangouts/other sms app

I know I can use broadcast receivers, but as I have discovered most of apps abort the broadcasts within and those do not propagate.

I want to set the MyApp as a default app and within it set the secondary preferred app to achieve my goal.
The problem starts with how to send broadcast only to the secondary app like Hangouts as there might be more than one sms app in the system.

Comment: could you pls put some code? what have u tried?

Comment: The code is simple. I have my own sms app (just classes[service, broadcastReceiver, main activity] with creating notification within each) that can be set as default sms app.

The thing is in sending data further to other default sms apps.. I don't know how to send it only to the one that is choosen as a default. (By this time I have tried using simple startActivity with com.google.android.talk package for hangouts)